# Can なる be used like this?

Tags: usage

Is it possible to use one なる with two adverbs to indicate becoming two different things/states simultaneously? Can one say, for example, 速くて大きくなる to mean get quicker and bigger? Or would it have to be 速くなって大きくなる?

Edit: Changed 早く to 早くて.
Edit 2:早く changed to 速く.

Comment: 速く大きくなる means "to become quick and big", not 早く. (The answer to your question is "yes")

Comment: Comparatively, I rarely see that kanji used. I figured 早く informally encompasses "quickly".

Comment: To make sure, you want to talk about something (say, smartphones or jet planes) that becomes faster and larger at the same time, right? Not something/someone that grows quickly?

Comment: Yes, I am asking whether なる  can be used as I did above to mean change in two different ways simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we have this long and easy sentence:

> iPhone 6 Plusは速くなって、(かつ)大きくなった。
>   iPhone 6 Plus became faster, and (at the same time) became larger.

You can omit the first なる like this:

> iPhone 6 Plusは速くて、(かつ)大きくなった。
>   iPhone 6 Plus became faster and (at the same time) larger.

Note that, in this form, the comma is optional. 「iPhone 6 Plusは速くて大きくなった」 is also fine, and this is the answer to your question.

The reminder is to avoid confusion. We can even omit this て and say like this:

> iPhone 6 Plusは速く、大きくなった。
>   iPhone 6 Plus became faster and larger.

This simple and bold sentence is typically suitable for an ad. But in this form, **comma is important**. Without the comma after 速く, this sentence suddenly appears as ambiguous and confusing, because 速く may serve as an adverb which modifies 大きく:

> [?] iPhone 6 Plusは速く大きくなった。
>   iPhone 6 Plus became quickly larger. [?]
>   iPhone 6 became larger (and it happened sooner than expected). [?]

This sentence would eventually be understood correctly with the aid of the context, because the topic is iPhone. But when we just hear "はやくおおきくなる", it is usually interpreted as "to grow quickly".

Answer (score 0):

"早くて大きくなる" sounds to me a bit weird since literally it translates into "to grow early." Do you mean "premature growth" by that?

"早くなって大きくなる" sounds to me "to grow swift and bigger," that is both "早く" and "大きく" sound as adjectives.

Comment: Sorry, the first example had a typo.